# HTMX: on click, update a form input and then submit the form

Tags: javascript, forms, htmx

I'm using [htmx](https://htmx.org/) in a HTML form in a page basically looking like this:

```html
<form id="my_form" method="post"  hx-post="{{ MY_TARGET_URL }}" hx-trigger="click from:.btn delay:100ms">

   <input type="hidden" name="state" value="" id="id_state">

   <!-- my form contains other inputs as well -->

</form>

<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1" data-state="1">Submit 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2" data-state="2">Submit 2</button>
```

The HTML page also includes the following JavaScript code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () =>
    document.getElementById("id_state").value = element.dataset.state;
  );
});
```

Everything seems to work perfectly well like this: the user can submit the form either by clicking on  `Submit 1` or on `Submit 2`, the hidden input gets updated either with the value `1` or `2` and then 100 ms later the form is submitted, sending a POST request to the specified endpoint.

However, I can feel this solution is a bit hacky and inelegant. Do you see a cleaner way to achieve the same thing, without "delay"?

Comment: The buttons are not part of your form, and you are not explicitly triggering the form submission anywhere in the code you have shown us - so that delay must come from the library you are using there.

Comment: I haven't used htmx, but why are your buttons not just standard buttons inside the `form`? Then you could have `name="state" value="1"` on one of them and `name="state" value="2"` on the other, and the `state` field would take the value from the button that was pressed.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
@CBroe the form submission is triggered by the attributes `hx-post` and `hx-trigger` in the above code.
@T.J.Crowder my buttons are outside the form for various reasons (the form in the body of a `bootstrap 5` modal and the buttons are in its footer) but I'll consider your alternative, thank you...
Now, what if I want for instance to update the selected option in `<select>` of my form? I'm affraid I'll need the help of someone having a good understanding of `htmx` for that.

Comment: @scūriolus Update the value of the select to what? Its not clear what you want

Comment: @Jodes Broadly speaking, I want to run custom JS code (let's consider a function `myFunction` for instance) before to submit the form & to send a POST request **using HTMX**. The above code already **works fine** on my machine but as explained I find it a bit clumsy.

Comment: @scūriolus You should look into htmx:beforeRequest event for any pre-submit custom js.

Comment: @mariodev that's probably what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

This should work?

HTML:

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="{{ MY_TARGET_URL }}">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="" id="id_state">
<!-- other form inputs -->
</form>

<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1" data-state="1">Submit 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2" data-state="2">Submit 2</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.getElementById("id_state").value = element.dataset.state;
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    });
});
```

I'm sure you don't need a delay

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but as stated above, I'm using HTMX and not vanilla JS (cf. `hx-post= ...` in my code)